# Requests-HTML does not render

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests, python-requests-html

I wanted to scrape the [Midjourney](https://midjourney.com) website, as usual I went to requests-html which I had previously worked with on a famous dynamic website called [Digikala](https://digikala.com). **The problem is that the rendering fails and I can't select the images!**

Using `requests_html.HTMLSession`:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()
response = session.get('https://midjourney.com/showcase/top/')
response.html.arender(timeout=60, sleep=5)

print(response.html.xpath('//img'))  # Output: []
```

And with `requests_html.AsyncHTMLSession`:

```py
from requests_html import AsyncHTMLSession

asession = AsyncHTMLSession()
response = await asession.get('https://midjourney.com/showcase/top/')
await response.html.arender(timeout=60, sleep=5)

print(response.html.xpath('//img'))  # Output: []
```

I tried all kinds of ways, including in this issue: 
https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/294

The result with selenium was like this:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()  # Also tested on Chrome
driver.get('https://midjourney.com/showcase/top/')

print(driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//img'))
# Output:
# [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b475751b-5ab3-4da8-b68b-523ceaa1ad5e", element="62660cb6-495b-434b-9bf0-80ff7a7df544")>,
#  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b475751b-5ab3-4da8-b68b-523ceaa1ad5e", element="8584c640-460c-422e-bd56-41327a745cee")>,
#  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b475751b-5ab3-4da8-b68b-523ceaa1ad5e", element="90f29838-1a88-4f2b-b4f7-b143af549a0b")>,
#  <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b475751b-5ab3-4da8-b68b-523ceaa1ad5e", element="7eca7e52-d807-4a1c-9b4b-cc9d4c98d728")>,
   ...]
```

A solution to work with [requests-html](https://requests.readthedocs.io/projects/requests-html/en/latest/)...

Comment: Requests-html is deprecated, not having been updated since a few years back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get that data with Requests (*not* requests-html - that is deprecated).

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import json

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

url = 'https://midjourney.com/showcase/top/'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

soup = bs(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
script_w_data = soup.select_one('script[id="__NEXT_DATA__"]').text
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(script_w_data)['props']['pageProps']['jobs'])
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    _job_type   _service    avatar_job_id   cover_job_id    current_status  enqueue_time    flagged grid_id grid_num    guild_id    hidden  id  image_paths is_published    low_priority    metered mod_hidden  platform    platform_channel    platform_channel_id platform_message_id platform_thread_id  prompt  ranking_score_average   type    user_id username    full_command    reference_job_id    reference_image_num _parsed_params.anime    _parsed_params.aspect   _parsed_params.creative _parsed_params.fast _parsed_params.hd   _parsed_params.no   _parsed_params.quality  _parsed_params.style    _parsed_params.test _parsed_params.testp    _parsed_params.tile _parsed_params.upanime  _parsed_params.upbeta   _parsed_params.uplight  _parsed_params.version  _parsed_params.vibe _parsed_params.video    event.height    event.textPrompt    event.imagePrompts  event.width event.batchSize event.seedImageURL  event.eventType event.test  _parsed_params  _parsed_params.chaos    _parsed_params.iw
0   diffusion_upsample_beta main    0e186767-a83b-476d-986a-d070005a6ad3    None    completed   2022-11-25 16:13:29.877393  True    None    None    None    False   c6d075cd-a5e8-4f0b-a3fe-8b8b54ddc872    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/c6d075cd-a5e8-4f0b-a3fe-8b8b54ddc872/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord Untracked   994851354122133514  1045734242895798272 None    the primordial darkness embodying a greek god, erebus wearing ancient greek glothing, galaxy with solar system as background, [cinematic, soft studio lighting, backlighting, dark background]  1.791538    upscale 210229354716725248  Xypherenz   the primordial darkness embodying a greek god, erebus wearing ancient greek glothing, galaxy with solar system as background, [cinematic, soft studio lighting, backlighting, dark background] --ar 2:3 --upbeta --q 2 --v 4    9331bf87-a997-4632-b2b0-59b432cf0b24    3   False   2:3 False   False   False   []  2.0     False   False   False   False   True    False   4   False   False   2432    [the primordial darkness embodying a greek god, erebus wearing ancient greek glothing, galaxy with solar system as background, [cinematic, soft studio lighting, backlighting, dark background]]    None    1664    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/9331bf87-a997-4632-b2b0-59b432cf0b24/0_3.png beta-upscale    False   NaN NaN NaN
1   diffusion_upsample_beta main    None    None    completed   2022-11-09 16:02:49.832468  True    None    None    None    False   dfc6f7fa-52b8-42e7-98d0-32d931f8d005    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/dfc6f7fa-52b8-42e7-98d0-32d931f8d005/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord Untracked   1011055541990207579 1039933604953870409 None    bedroom melting into the ocean  1.774527    upscale 841154151537836072  Falcon  bedroom melting into the ocean --ar 2:3 --testp --creative  d970ee59-1984-40a4-a2d8-ddaf5e164276    0   False   2:3 True    False   False   []  NaN     False   True    False   False   False   False   testp   False   False   2432    [bedroom melting into the ocean]    None    1664    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/d970ee59-1984-40a4-a2d8-ddaf5e164276/0_0.png beta-upscale    False   NaN NaN NaN
2   None    None    None    None    completed   2022-07-26 15:12:36.428174  True    None    None    None    False   fa55db49-7b20-4813-b6b8-185343e34e8b    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/fa55db49-7b20-4813-b6b8-185343e34e8b/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord DM  991780400764551308  1001508025569390612 None    aerial view of a giant fish tank shaped like a tower in the middle of new york city, 8k octane render, photorealistic   1.752420    upscale 404209174109487104  Hanu    aerial view of a giant fish tank shaped like a tower in the middle of new york city, 8k octane render, photorealistic --ar 9:20 9b63079e-dd11-4f9c-adbf-403ce63c90fb    3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2304    [aerial view of a giant fish tank shaped like a tower in the middle of new york city, 8k octane render, photorealistic] None    1024    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/9b63079e-dd11-4f9c-adbf-403ce63c90fb/0_3.png imagine False   NaN NaN NaN
3   None    None    None    None    completed   2022-08-02 12:55:45.749907  True    None    None    198648363342626816  False   d0f67afd-01db-4009-bc45-318c200834c3    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/d0f67afd-01db-4009-bc45-318c200834c3/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord art-room    1003923990567460884 1004010949772066837 None    milkyway in a glass bottle, 4K, unreal engine, octane render    1.744470    upscale 198686832949592064  Deeds   <https://s.mj.run/7t0-6y9_kVE> milkyway in a glass bottle, 4K, unreal engine, octane render --ar 9:16   da6a45a3-3a7a-4172-bfdd-ecee23a4bbe9    2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1792    [milkyway in a glass bottle, 4K, unreal engine, octane render]  None    1024    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/da6a45a3-3a7a-4172-bfdd-ecee23a4bbe9/0_2.png imagine False   NaN NaN NaN
4   diffusion_upsample_detailed main    0f32ba27-55b5-434d-a5cf-11ae422d49a3    4d6c8b0e-ccc8-4471-a2b8-3d7a087373bd    completed   2022-12-02 15:20:03.939279  False   None    None    662267976984297473  False   8f5faed3-3f16-40c6-ae32-546ae5f396c1    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/8f5faed3-3f16-40c6-ae32-546ae5f396c1/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord Untracked   1008571165893197845 1048257604851335269 None    Western Cowboy riding his horse at night under the milky way galaxy, desert, HDR, anime scene,  1.732337    upscale 1035250687602335775 KatGatan    Western Cowboy riding his horse at night under the milky way galaxy, desert, HDR, anime scene, --v 4 --q 2 --ar 2:3 f7ea89b9-428e-4ec3-9a7b-885d1f8a0742    0   False   2:3 False   False   False   []  2.0     False   False   False   False   False   False   4   False   False   1792    [Western Cowboy riding his horse at night under the milky way galaxy, desert, HDR, anime scene,]    None    1152    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/f7ea89b9-428e-4ec3-9a7b-885d1f8a0742/0_0.png upscale False   NaN NaN NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
89  None    None    None    None    completed   2022-07-21 06:39:51.231882  False   None    None    None    False   c6c339cb-9ddf-4235-a416-a9afb8799ebc    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/c6c339cb-9ddf-4235-a416-a9afb8799ebc/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord DM  994987591977926677  1016420813127286955 None    handsome cute black dragon in snowy forest, dnd character, background focus, fantasy, magic, realistic textured skin, hawk feather, hawk wings, lizard legs, lizard pose, big eyes, clear clean, by lya kushinov, Avetetsuya Studios, Alexandra Fomina artstation, by Makoto Shinkai, digital 2D, matte painting    1.660050    upscale 927684624149250099  CGPlayground    <https://s.mj.run/X2Q0G453wvQ> handsome cute black dragon in snowy forest, dnd character, background focus, fantasy, magic, realistic textured skin, hawk feather, hawk wings, lizard legs, lizard pose, big eyes, clear clean, by lya kushinov, Avetetsuya Studios, Alexandra Fomina artstation, by Makoto Shinkai, digital 2D, matte painting --test --ar 9:14 --uplight --stop 90 --no dof   f5e56fb5-0b05-4e5a-8ca5-ef90516202fd    3   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1536    [handsome cute black dragon in snowy forest, dnd character, background focus, fantasy, magic, realistic textured skin, hawk feather, hawk wings, lizard legs, lizard pose, big eyes, clear clean, by lya kushinov, Avetetsuya Studios, Alexandra Fomina artstation, by Makoto Shinkai, digital 2D, matte painting, [dof]]   None    1024    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/f5e56fb5-0b05-4e5a-8ca5-ef90516202fd/0_3.png imagine False   NaN NaN NaN
90  None    None    58502949-0b6f-4727-a5c4-01cf67bdf65d    1324c187-0a4d-4042-a1e4-09254111e4ae    completed   2022-07-22 09:52:10.253699  False   None    None    662267976984297473  False   2c80a6c6-43a8-4c1f-b50b-5ebfed7dd25f    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/2c80a6c6-43a8-4c1f-b50b-5ebfed7dd25f/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord misc-threads    966618919039283230  999980598057762856  999233365129576459  intricate colourfully painted carved wood paneling, dark souls, ivory and copper , artstation   1.659942    upscale 424912627400179714  GoatHanger  <https://s.mj.run/Ex4dB8_bGNU> intricate colourfully painted carved wood paneling, dark souls, ivory and copper , artstation --h 512 --test cb8a13c5-dd7a-499b-bfc5-10be29b9d6bb    2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2048    [intricate colourfully painted carved wood paneling, dark souls, ivory and copper , artstation] None    1024    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/cb8a13c5-dd7a-499b-bfc5-10be29b9d6bb/0_2.png imagine False   NaN NaN NaN
91  None    None    None    None    completed   2022-06-16 06:40:52.234283  False   None    None    None    False   92ec03ab-bae2-4705-bee4-54408ed9c0e2    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/92ec03ab-bae2-4705-bee4-54408ed9c0e2/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord misc-threads    966618919039283230  986883981226172447  983753950606020618  dark red paper with intricate designs,tarot card ,a mandelbulb fractal southeast asian buddha statue,full of golden layers, flowers, cloud, vines, mushrooms, swirles, curves, wave,by Hokusai and Mike Mignola, trending on artstation,elaborate dark red ink illustration 1.659813    upscale 981903338079674420  xiuxiu  dark red paper with intricate designs,tarot card ,a mandelbulb fractal southeast asian buddha statue,full of golden layers, flowers, cloud, vines, mushrooms, swirles, curves, wave,by Hokusai and Mike Mignola, trending on artstation,elaborate dark red ink illustration —w 1152 —h 2432 ad206ec9-cc2b-44a2-b629-3cf0ed857771    0   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2048    dark red paper with intricate designs,tarot card ,a mandelbulb fractal southeast asian buddha statue,full of golden layers, flowers, cloud, vines, mushrooms, swirles, curves, wave,by Hokusai and Mike Mignola, trending on artstation,elaborate dark red ink illustration None    1024    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/ad206ec9-cc2b-44a2-b629-3cf0ed857771/0_0.png imagine False   NaN NaN NaN
92  None    None    None    None    completed   2022-07-26 18:31:37.918437  False   None    None    None    False   11eda75a-2697-4cba-9d76-5fad35ab69e9    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/11eda75a-2697-4cba-9d76-5fad35ab69e9/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord DM  986328869491576873  1001557714922639442 None    portrait of the cutest red fox ever, fluffy, photorealistic, soft lighting, unreal engine   1.659696    upscale 986307851339321364  pickersberry    <https://s.mj.run/gLL2SMLw6UY> portrait of the cutest red fox ever, fluffy, photorealistic, soft lighting, unreal engine --ar 3:4 --uplight --stop 80   bf3f8513-cf77-476a-ac67-3f30bddf9148    2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 1280    [portrait of the cutest red fox ever, fluffy, photorealistic, soft lighting, unreal engine] None    1024    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/bf3f8513-cf77-476a-ac67-3f30bddf9148/0_2.png imagine False   NaN NaN NaN
93  None    None    None    None    completed   2022-07-27 14:39:24.924787  False   None    None    1003840997890981908 False   82e74199-e9f4-49cb-ba28-c20378a0ac2f    [https://cdn.midjourney.com/82e74199-e9f4-49cb-ba28-c20378a0ac2f/0_0.png]   True    None    None    False   discord midjourney-chat 1003840998348177511 1014322238989799474 None    incredibly powerful Anime Girl, created by Hideaki Anno + Katsuhiro Otomo +Rumiko Takahashi, Movie poster style, box office hit, a masterpiece of storytelling, main character center focus, monsters + mech creatures locked in combat, nuclear explosions paint sky, highly detailed 8k   1.659574    upscale 339197478777782274  drumm   <https://s.mj.run/0LFGnVVLtDQ> incredibly powerful Anime Girl, created by Hideaki Anno + Katsuhiro Otomo +Rumiko Takahashi, Movie poster style, box office hit, a masterpiece of storytelling, main character center focus, monsters + mech creatures locked in combat, nuclear explosions paint sky, highly detailed 8k --ar 9:18  d71eff54-8e1d-4d2e-a71c-b87b6f3e4659    2   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN 2048    [incredibly powerful Anime Girl, created by Hideaki Anno + Katsuhiro Otomo +Rumiko Takahashi, Movie poster style, box office hit, a masterpiece of storytelling, main character center focus, monsters + mech creatures locked in combat, nuclear explosions paint sky, highly detailed 8k] None    1024    1   https://cdn.midjourney.com/d71eff54-8e1d-4d2e-a71c-b87b6f3e4659/0_2.png imagine False   NaN NaN NaN
94 rows × 58 columns
```

Comment: Does it work for all dynamic websites?

Comment: My response fully addresses your initial question, @ArtinMohammadi. That's how StackOverflow works. There is no solution for **all** websites.

Comment: I understand that this script doesn't always work, but there's no rush for now, maybe a solution will be found for **requests-html**.

Comment: Requests-html is deprecated, as stated above. Good luck mate.

Comment: Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted if it addressed your question. @ArtinMohammadi